# Application Crashes due to Low memory

Tags: objective-c, ipad

My app crashes after playing for more than 30 min on some screen due to low memory will my app get reject due to this?
actually i tried a lot to solve but it shows no trace in instrument i even did all permutation combination of code by commenting checking what causing the problem but i was not successful to solve it yet. 
its an ipad application 3.2 sdk
I have notice many app which crash due to low memory and they are happily on app store

Any clues,suggestion ,advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if your app is not rejected, your users will not be happy about your app crashing, and rate it 1/5. You should really try harder to fix it ;-)

Comment: ya im working on it but may be for next version.But ur absolutely right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bill Bumgarner recently wrote up a blog post on using **Heapshot Analysis** to catch memory growth when some of the more traditional techniques fail.  Although his write up is in the context of a Mac OS application, the technique should be equally applicable to iOS. Bill walks you through using the Allocations Instrument to do Heapshot Analysis and track down your leak.

Perhaps this technique will help you track down your memory issues.

See [bbum's weblog-o-mat  » Blog Archive » When is a Leak not a Leak? Using Heapshot Analysis to Find Undesirable Memory Growth](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)